# vba code running but not fetching data

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to vba.

I am trying to use below code by David Zemens to fetch data from yelp

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub find()
'Uses late binding, or add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library 
'  and change variable Types to use intellisense
Dim ie As Object 'InternetExplorer.Application
Dim html As Object 'HTMLDocument
Dim Listings As Object 'IHTMLElementCollection
Dim l As Object 'IHTMLElement
Dim r As Long
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate "http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=boutique&find_loc=New+York%2C+NY&ns=1&ls=3387133dfc25cc99#start=10"
        ' Don't show window
        'Wait until IE is done loading page
        Do While .readyState <> 4
            Application.StatusBar = "Downloading information, Please wait..."
            DoEvents
            Sleep 200
        Loop
        Set html = .Document
    End With
    Set Listings = html.getElementsByTagName("LI") ' ## returns the list
    For Each l In Listings
        '## make sure this list item looks like the listings Div Class:
        '   then, build the string to put in your cell
        If InStr(1, l.innerHTML, "media-block clearfix media-block-large main-attributes") > 0 Then
            Range("A1").Offset(r, 0).Value = l.innerText
            r = r + 1
        End If
    Next

Set html = Nothing
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Problem is that it's not getting any data from the source.

Regards

Comment: First off, `Private Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)` should be `Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)` and second, what are you trying to fetch? The store names?

Comment: Hi,First accept my thanks for your response.I am trying to get business names,address,telephone numbers.Kind regards

Comment: You need to figure out what tags are holding in the data you need from the source code of the page. Get those tags and strip them from everything that you don't need and display the data in the range of your desire. Most of it is pretty much done for you. I tried your code and the reason why it is not returning something is because `media-block clearfix media-block-large main-attributes` does not exist in the source code of your target page.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.Going to try it out

Comment: Still not working.Can anyone help?

Comment: Any help or any point outs??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of work to be done.

Here's something that you can start with. Hopefully, you will be able to find the other pieces of information using the same logic. This will print business names in the immediate window. I've found the business names in meta tag description.

I've changed the sleep amount to 5 seconds. IE will be able to fully load and the rest of the code will be processed reliably. The initial 200 milliseconds gave results once every couple of runs. I guess this depends how fast your computer is so 5 seconds is pretty safe I guess.

```
Option Explicit

Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub find()

'Uses late binding, or add reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library
'  and change variable Types to use intellisense
 Dim returnstring As String 'this is going to hold boutiques names
Dim ie As Object 'InternetExplorer.Application
Dim html As Object 'HTMLDocument
Dim meta As Object 'IHTMLElementCollection
Dim l As Object 'IHTMLElement
Dim r As Long
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate "http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=boutique&find_loc=New+York%2C+NY&ns=1&ls=3387133dfc25cc99#start=10"
        ' Don't show window
        'Wait until IE is done loading page
        Do While .readyState <> 4
            Application.StatusBar = "Downloading information, Please wait..."
            DoEvents
            Sleep 5000
        Loop
        Set html = .Document
    End With
    Set meta = html.GetElementsByTagName("META") ' ## returns attribures
    Dim m As Object

    For Each m In meta
    If InStr(m.Content, "Reviews on Boutique in New York -") > 0 Then
    returnstring = Replace(m.Content, "Reviews on Boutique in New York -", "")
    End If
    Next
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(Split(returnstring, ","))
    Debug.Print (Split(returnstring, ",")(i))
    Next
Set html = Nothing
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Myoutput:
[image]

Comment: Hi,thanks for your time and efforts.Problem is still same, not getting any results.Am trying to debug.will post result if i can make it to work.Kind Regards

Comment: Not getting any errors, code seems to be running endlessly without any output.

Comment: It works fine bro. Is there anything blocking IE when it starts? http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=04097054447765086803

Comment: Still same for me, Even using file you provided.Nothing is blocking IE. I checked it with IE visible option.

Comment: How does your IE take time to load up and load up the page?

Comment: IE loads fine. Does less than in 5 seconds

Comment: Thanks, I was missing a simple step.Working fine